# How to pass the sitename in ProjectName.deploy.cmd

Tags: deployment, msbuild, msdeploy

I am trying to run the ProjectName.deply.cmd that is generated by MSBuild when the paramter `/p:DeployOnBuild=True` is passed. One of the argument "ComputerName" is to be passed as `https://WebServer01:8172/MSDeploy.axd?SiteName=MySiteName`. My command line would be

```
ProjectName.deploy.cmd /Y /M:https://WebServer01:8172/MSDeploy.axd?Site=MySiteName 
                       -AllowUntrusted /U:DeployUserName /P:Password /A:Basic
```

It returns

```
Error: Unrecognized argument 'MySiteName'. All arguments must begin with "-".
```

the actual command that is executed is

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\\msdeploy.exe" 
    -source:package='Y:\ProjectName.zip'
    -dest:auto,computerName='https://WebServer01:8172/MSDeploy.axd?Site',userName='DeployUserName',password='Password',authtype='Basic',includeAcls='False'
    -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension 
    -disableLink:CertificateExtension 
    -setParamFile:"Y:\ProjectName.SetParameters.xml"
    MySiteName
    -AllowUntrusted
```

Notice that the argument to /M `https://WebServer01:8172/MSDeploy.axd?Site=MySiteName` is split into two arguments and thus creating `computerName='https://WebServer01:8172/MSDeploy.axd?Site'` and and extra argument `MySiteName`.

I have gone through [Running a deployment package with quoted parameters fails in Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2537134) but that takes care of only `ArgMsDeployAdditionalFlags` and not the arguments e.g. `/M:ComputerName`.

When the SiteName is not passed, I can do the deployment fine with an user that had admin rights on the server but when a standard IIS user DeployUserName is used I get 401

```
ProjectName.deploy.cmd /Y /M:https://WebServer01:8172/MSDeploy.axd
                       -AllowUntrusted /U:DeployUserName /P:Password /A:Basic
```

The server returns 401

```
Error Code: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED
More Information: Connected to the remote computer ("WebServer01") using the Web 
Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the
correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and
that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.
Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.

Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

The permissions for that user are fine as the publish from `VS2012` with `MSDeploy` profile using that user works just fine. I can also build `msdeploy.exe` command and that also runs fine. I have to use the `ProjectName.deploy.cmd` as it is being produced as part of `Team Build` from `TFS2010`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried quoting the argument?

```
ProjectName.deploy.cmd /Y "/M:https://WebServer01:8172/MSDeploy.axd?Site=MySiteName" 
                   -AllowUntrusted /U:DeployUserName /P:Password /A:Basic
```

Comment: That was a typo in the question. I have fixed it. The issue is not the argument itself. It is the way = is handled by the command prompt and then arranged in the deploy.cmd script to be further passed down to msdeploy.exe.

Comment: I am sure that I tried this along with other variations to escape the = but that day none of them worked :( Today I started with this and it worked in the very first try. There were few other security related issues but those were straight forward. With this working I won't need admin privileges for the deployment user (which is what I wanted). Thanks @Richard for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Thought I'd add to the answer for anyone else like me that stumbles upon this trying to figure out why this doesn't work, and who'd like the equivalent msdeploy command.

As mentioned in the comments quoting the argument won't work due to a bug in how the arguments are parsed, from MS docs:

> At the time of writing, due to a bug in the Web Publishing Pipeline
> (WPP), you can't run the .deploy.cmd file using an endpoint address
> that includes a query string. In this scenario, you need to deploy
> your web package by using MSDeploy.exe directly.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-web-packages

So, instead, you should use MSDeploy directly. Equivalent to the deploy.cmd arguments in the question:

```
MSDeploy.exe -source:package='<fullPathToDeployable>\<projectName>.zip' 
-dest:auto,computerName="https://<ipOrDnsName>:8172/MSDeploy.axd",userName="<userName>",password="<pwd>",authtype="Basic",includeAcls="False" 
-verb:sync 
-disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
-disableLink:ContentExtension 
-disableLink:CertificateExtension 
-setParamFile:"<fullPathToDeployable>\<projectName>.SetParameters.xml"  
-setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="<siteName>" 
-AllowUntrusted
```

(replace angle-bracketed words)

Comment: I needed *computerName="* `https://<ipOrDnsName>:8172/MSDeploy.axd` **?site=<siteName>** *"* specifically to emulate Visual Studio deploy behavior, thanks alot for this Martin! Finally got my deployment to succeed.